# Maven3 - Is it possible to globally exclude a transitive dependency?

Tags: maven-3

Artifacts such as those developed by Apache are commonly used by several dependencies. We've placed some of them in our Shared Libraries in our application server.

The problem is that in each `pom.xml`we have to exclude those dependencies in several direct dependencies we have. So my question is: does [maven-3](/questions/tagged/maven-3) have a feature that allows us to exclude a transitive dependency globally?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39979760/363573

Comment: Setting the transitive dependency as a provided direct dependency solved my problem. Thanks!