# Exclusions in dependency management using wildcard

Tags: java, maven

I have a **project A** which creates 10 artifacts with same group id . For example generated artifacts from the **project A** will be -

```
<groupId>com.example.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>A1</artifactId>
<version>v1</version>

<groupId>com.example.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>A2</artifactId>
<version>v2</version>
```

Likewise from A1 to A10 and v1 to v10 . Group Id remains same.

The generated artifacts needs to be used in another **project B** but I need to exclude two dependencies which are common to all the ten artifacts  generated by Project A.

I know I can add dependency management tag in Project B's pom.xml with explicit *exclusions* tag.

What I am looking for is a less verbose way of excluding those two dependencies ? I tried with

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            <version>*</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>  
 </dependencyManagement>
```

which is not working .

Is there any less verbose way ?

Comment: First I would suggest to clean up the original artifacts cause adding a mockito-core is simply wrong ..only as a transitive dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you declare the mockito dependency as a one provide.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>YOUR VERSION</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Note:** *The dependency won't end up inside the build artifact but it's still available during test*s

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716310/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-a-maven-dependency-globally) too.
Regards.

Comment: you can specify version interval as well , like <version>[2.0.0,]</version>

Comment: The scope of the dependency made it to work. Now my pom is pretty clean

Comment: If you really using mockito you should define it with `<scope>test</scope>` cause that usually belong only to test which in the end will not being packaged into the resulting war.